# for loop through text file using windows cmd

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd

I have a large nmap results text file on a windows box that I need to loop through, pulling out the IPs and OS type only. I could easily do this in Linux but unfortunately, that isn't an option on this project. Below is output from nmap for one node.

```
Nmap scan report for 10.16.7.14  
Host is up (0.0095s latency)  
Not shown: 999 closed ports  
PORT     STATE SERVICE  
1443/tcp open  ies-lm  
Device type: general purpose  
Running: Linux 2.4.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.4  
OS details: Linux 2.4.18 - 2.4.35 (likely embedded)  
Network Distance: 1 hop
```

I've already tried several for loops but I'm no expert and I need this for a project tomorrow morning.

I'd like the for loop to echo the IP and OS associated with this node.

```
Example:  
IP = 10.16.7.14  
OS = Linux
```

I'm fine if it says "Nmap scan report for 10.16.7.14" as well. Doesn't need to be pretty, just needs to be functional. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following batch file can be used if the data are stored in a text file like `nmap.txt` to get the data of interest written into file `IP_OS.txt`:

```
@echo off
if exist "nmap.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3,5" %%I in ("nmap.txt") do (
        if "%%I %%J %%K" == "Nmap scan report" (
            echo IP = %%L
        ) else if "%%I %%J" == "OS details:" (
            echo OS = %%K
        )
    )
) >"IP_OS.txt"
if exist "IP_OS.txt" for %%I in ("IP_OS.txt") do if %%~zI == 0 del "IP_OS.txt"
```

The command **FOR** with option `/F` processes the lines in the text file `nmap.txt` with ignoring empty lines. The option `usebackq` is needed to get the file name enclosed in double quotes, although not really needed on this example, not interpreted as string to process, but as file name of a text file of which lines should be processed by **FOR**.

Non-empty lines are split to substrings using as string delimiters normal space and horizontal tab character. By default only the first space/tab separated substring is assigned to specified loop variable `I`. By using option `tokens=1-3,5` the default behavior is overwritten as telling **FOR** that of interest are the first, second, third and fifth space/tab separated string.

**FOR** with option `/F` uses by default `eol=;` to define end of line character. If the first space/tab separated substring of the line (not the first substring referenced with `tokens=`) starts with a semicolon, the entire line is ignored for further processing. In this case it is not necessary to change the default end of line character behavior.

So **FOR** reads a line like `Nmap scan report for 10.16.7.14` and splits it up with the used options to

1. `Nmap` (not starting with a semicolon) assigned to specified loop variable `I`,
2. `scan` assigned to second loop variable according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is `J`,
3. `report` assigned to third loop variable `K`,
4. `for` ignored by **FOR** as not specified in `tokens=` option,
5. `10.16.7.14` assigned to fourth loop variable `L`.

This behavior with assigning multiple strings to multiple loop variables is the reason why **FOR** loop variables are case sensitive in comparison to environment variables which are interpreted case insensitive by `cmd.exe`.

The line `OS details: Linux 2.4.18 - 2.4.35 (likely embedded)` is split up to

1. `OS` (not starting with a semicolon) assigned to specified loop variable `I`,
2. `details:` assigned to second loop variable `J`,
3. `Linux` assigned to third loop variable `K`,
4. `2.4.18` ignored,
5. `-` assigned to fourth loop variable `L`
6. and rest of line is ignored.

The first **IF** condition compares case sensitive the first **three** substrings separated with a space between each substring enclosed in double quotes with the string `"Nmap scan report"`. The double quotes are included by **IF** on comparing the two strings left and right of string equal operator `==`. The IP assigned to **fourth** loop variable `L` is output on a positive match on string comparison.

The second **IF** condition compares case sensitive the first **two** substrings separated with a space between the two substrings enclosed in double quotes with the string `"OS details:"`. The OS assigned to **third** loop variable `K` is output on a positive match on this string comparison.

Everything output during execution of **FOR** is redirected into file `IP_OS.txt`.

The last line of the batch file uses once again command **FOR**, but this time without option `/F` to just run the loop once with `"IP_OS.txt"` assigned to loop variable `I`. `%%~zI` references the file size in bytes of the file of which name is assigned currently to the loop variable `I`. The output file is deleted if its file size is 0 bytes, i.e. the output file is empty because of no data of interest were found in file `nmap.txt`.

It is also possible to use **FOR** with option `/F` to run in background `%ComSpec% /c` with a command line specified between two `'` and let **FOR** capture the output written by the command line to handle **STDOUT** of this command process and process it line by line after started Windows command process finished.

Example:

```
@echo off
(
    for /F "tokens=1-3,5" %%I in ('type "nmap.txt"') do (
        if "%%I %%J %%K" == "Nmap scan report" (
            echo IP = %%L
        ) else if "%%I %%J" == "OS details:" (
            echo OS = %%K
        )
    )
) >"IP_OS.txt"
if exist "IP_OS.txt" for %%I in ("IP_OS.txt") do if %%~zI == 0 del "IP_OS.txt"
```

In this case **FOR** runs with Windows being installed into `C:\Windows` in background:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c type "nmap.txt"
```

Any command line other than `type "nmap.txt"` can be also executed like the command line executing the application which creates the data in `nmap.txt`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `type /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).